# Heroku Rake Issues `require': cannot load such file -- /app/db:version (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I have a rails app that works on my development box, i am putting it up on heroku and everything works fine except whenever I run a rake db.. command it does the command but at the end it gives me the following error:

> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': cannot load such file -- /app/db:version (LoadError)
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in`block in require'
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in`require'
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:11:in
>   `block in require_files'
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:10:in`
>   each'
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:10:in
>   `require_files'
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:86:in`plugin_rails_init'
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.1/lib/minitest.rb:80:in
>   `block in init_plugins'
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.1/lib/minitest.rb:78:in`
>   each'
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.1/lib/minitest.rb:78:in
>   `init_plugins'
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.1/lib/minitest.rb:129:in`
>   run'
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:72:in `run'
>           from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.1/lib/minitest.rb:62:in`
>   block in autorun'

I have tried adding the gems railties and minitest into my gem file.  I have deleted my heroku app and started from scratch again.

I have deleted the gemlock file and ran bundle install and bundle check

I have specified the ruby version in my gem file

Below is my gem file

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
ruby "2.4.0"
gem 'rake', '~> 12.0'
gem 'railties', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.10', '>= 5.10.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
#gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
gem  'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production gem 'redis', '~> 3.0' Use ActiveModel has_secure_password gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7' Use Capistrano for deployment gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'peddler', '~> 1.4.1'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.8'
gem "pry-rails", group:"development"
gem 'chartkick', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.1'
gem "groupdate"
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.1'
 #required for devise
 gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
 #gem 'foundation-rails'

 gem 'whenever', require: false

# export to excel
gem 'axlsx_rails', '~> 0.4.0'
gem 'axlsx', '2.1.0.pre'
gem 'roo'
gem 'rubyzip', '~> 1.1.0'
#gem 'zip-zip' #
#gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
#gem 'foundation-datepicker-rails'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.5'

gem "wysiwyg-rails"
gem "font-awesome-rails"

gem 'stripe'
gem 'stripe_event', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1'

#gem 'koudoku'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'

gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'

gem "bootstrap-switch-rails"

gem 'elasticemail', git: "git://github.com/klebervirgilio/elasticemail.git"

gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.1.1'

gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'

gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'

gem 'sidekiq'
#gem 'sinatra', github: 'sinatra/sinatra'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

 group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
 end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5' # was causing an error https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24063 moved outside development group

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
 end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
  gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I am at a loss, thank you

Comment: What command do you type to run rake task on Heroku?

Comment: when you run `heroku run rails c` what happens?

Comment: @MichałMłoźniak I type heroku rake db:migrate or even heroku rake db:version that error comes up.  BUT even though it has that error everything seems to be working.  Like, it does all the migrations and gives me the migration version

Comment: @SomeSchmo it works, it takes me to the irb, no error messages at all.  Only when i run heroku rake db...

The site seems to work just fine, so I'm not sure why it does that.  It has no issues on my local ubuntu instance on WSL.  So something on the production environment is causing it.  As if it is doing a final check or something but i guess if the preceding steps worked, it doesn't really impact the actual application.

But I would like to know what is causing it and to fix it if possible.  Thank you

Comment: hmm not sure. One suggestion might be to remove the forced gem versions since the versions you're forcing might not be compatible

Comment: tried taking out all the versions from the gem file, surprisingly site still worked but still had the error when running heroku run rake db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

The corrent syntax to run rake tasks on Heroku is `heroku run rake db:migrate`. In your command you missed `run`

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work

still has the same error

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are using rails 5 and have 12factor gem. `rails_12factor` gem is not required for rails 5 deployment on heroku.
Follow [heroku rails 5 deployment documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5) and it should solve the issue.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i removed that gem but still doesn't work.  I ended up removing all the gems and adding them back 1 by 1 but couldn't find the culprit.  Because my app requires certain gems, everytime it asked for a gem i would add it back then delete the gemfile.lock, bundle install, then push back to heroku.

At this point, it isn't really impacting my application.  maybe if i start a new app and include the gemfile and see if it errors out.

Thing is, it doesn't throw this error on my local machine.